# Rails: do not allow compile assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is any way to prevent the compiling of specific `*.scss` files from `assets/stylesheets`? I need to keep those files in `assets` not `public` directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove

```
 *= require_tree .
```

line from application.scss and require only the files you want to compile.